# how to update bar graph and also its legend without re-drawing it in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I want to update the stacked bar graph without re-drawing it. The data comes from a AJAX request.
My sample code is here http://jsfiddle.net/my8646oc/47/

```
    $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
        type: 'bar',
            animation: {
                duration: 1000
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
         legend: {
                    symbolHeight: '0',
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    horizontalAlign: 'right',
                     labelFormatter: function() {
                        return '<span>' + this.name + ': ' + this.yData[ 0 ] + '</span>';
                    },

                    y: -15,
                    useHTML: true
                },

        xAxis: {
            categories: []
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9],
            name: 'one'
        },
        {            data: [39.9],
        name: 'two'
}]

    });

    var i = 1;
    $('#update').click(function () {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        var newData = [{
            data: [39.9],
            name: 'one'
        },
        {            data: [49.9],
        name: 'two'
}];
        //chart.series[0].update({
        //    name: "TEST" + i++,
        //    data : 
        //});

         var ctr,
                    count,
                    len = chart.series.length,
                    len2 = newData.length;
                for ( ctr = 0; ctr < len; ctr = ctr + 1 ) {
                    for ( count = 0; count < len2; count = count + 1 ) {
                        if ( newData[ count ].name === chart.series[ ctr].name ) {
                            chart.series[ ctr ].setData( newData[ count ].data[ 0 ] );
                            delete newData[ count ];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }


    });
});
```

I have tried using setData and update only the series, in this case only the bar is updating not the legend. Any proper solution for this?? anyone??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know highcharts.js but by passing the data column as an array, the chart works.

```
chart.series[ ctr ].setData( newData[ count ].data[0] );
```

change to

```
chart.series[ ctr ].setData( newData[ count ].data );
```

**Update demo**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/my8646oc/49/)

Comment: in this case only the first data is updating in the bar and also no change in the legend( data in legend is not updating)

Comment: I've updated the demo, it's now showing both value. For the legend, you need to read the [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts)

Comment: Hi Slashsharp, i too have achieved this ( i have stated this below my code in the question ). My challenge was to update the legends. Gone through the documentation but nothing found. Can you please suggest anything to update the legend too?

Comment: You may use jQuery for updating your legend without redraw: http://jsfiddle.net/a77yxxgs/ but I am not sure why you don't want to redraw your chart.

Comment: It the requirement from my client friend @GrzegorzBlachlińskiNeed to do this without re-drawing only

Answer (score 0):

For this you want to use series.update() instead of series.setData().

Code:

```
chart.series[ ctr ].update({ data: newData[ count ].data[ 0 ] });
```

Updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/my8646oc/50/

Comment: Its giving some error @jlbriggs. it is not updating

Comment: Can you be more specific? It's updating for me.

Comment: the data with 'one' name is coming undefined in the legend and in the graph its only showing the bar with name  'two' @jibriggs

Comment: Hi @jlbriggs. Yes this is working, thanks to you the legend and graph both are updating but the bar graph is flowing of the container after updating..how can this be stopped?